# Why does `os.listdir` does not accept a path with "~"?

Tags: python, listdir

When using python if you have say:

```
dd="~/this/path/do/exist/"
```

and you do

```
os.listdir(dd)
```

you get

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno2] no such file or directory '~/this/path/do/exist/'
```

even though the path exists.

Why is this and how can it be corrected?

---

Furthermore if you pass a path with ~ using argparse it gets converted to a full path and this problem does not occur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~` is interpreted by the shell, which is why it works when you use it on the command line via argparse.

Use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to evaluate `~`.

```py
import os
os.path.expanduser("~/this/path/do/exist/")
```

If you are using `pathlib.Path`, you can use [`Path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.expanduser).

```py
from pathlib import Path
Path("~/this/path/do/exist/").expanduser()
```